# What is the meaning of yet in this sentence "well don't say anything.yet"?

Tags: meaning

Actually I am watching movie in which a boy proposes a girl to get married but the girl does not want to marry that boy. Here is the conversation happens between girl and boy.
Girl: I don't know what to say.
Boy: well don't say anything. Yet. Okay. This is my fault.

So I just want to know what is the meaning of "yet" here?

Comment: Don't say yes or no straight away; think about it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

> well don't say anything. ***Yet***. Okay. This is my fault.

I think it means: Don't say anything while you don't know what will happen.

Here is ***[yet](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/yet)*** is up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then.

So it can also be replaced with:

> Well don't say anything as yet.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't say anything yet." means the same as "Don't say anything right now."

Essentially, the young man is telling the young woman that she doesn't have to make this decision instantly; he's saying it is okay if she takes time to think it through and decide later. (Though in the context, anything but a happy "Yes!" is generally a bad sign, so the young man seems to realize that maybe this awkward proposal was a bad idea.)